# Merge two Class type variable into one C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two class type variable agreementsSTD  and agreementsStatePlans. How can I merge these into Agreements combinedSTDStatePlansAgreements?
My Class below:

```
public class Agreements
    {
        public string clientEnterpriseId { get; set; }
        public List<Agreement> agreements { get; set; }
        public List<ServiceAgreement> serviceAgreements { get; set; }
    }

Agreements agreementsSTD = await _mdmServiceClient.GetGroupDivisions(clientEnterpriseID, "DataTest");
Agreements agreementsStatePlans = await _mdmServiceClient.GetGroupDivisions(clientEnterpriseID, "Data2");
```

I have tried the method below, but it's not working. Do you know of any other ways to resolve this? Thank you!

```
Agreements combinedSTDStatePlansAgreements = new Agreements
            {
                clientEnterpriseId = agreementsSTD.clientEnterpriseId,
                agreements = agreementsSTD.agreements.Concat(agreementsStatePlans.agreements).ToList(),
                serviceAgreements = agreementsSTD.serviceAgreements.Concat(agreementsStatePlans.serviceAgreements).ToList()
            };
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, what error message do you get?

Comment: If I run this list separately, my server works fine. However, when I try to merge it, I get a server 500 error. I can't identify the cause of this issue because it is happening on the server.

Comment: Your server would have captured the logs somewhere. Such as systemd logs for Linux or Event Viewer for Windows

Comment: One of the lists is returning null and causing an error to be thrown

Answer (score 0):

One of the lists is returning null and causing an error to be thrown. I have resolved below way. Thanks!

```
Agreements combinedSTDStatePlansAgreements = new Agreements();
            if (agreementsSTD != null && agreementsStatePlans != null)
            {
                
                if (agreementsSTD.agreements != null && agreementsStatePlans.agreements != null)
                    combinedSTDStatePlansAgreements.agreements = agreementsSTD.agreements.Concat(agreementsStatePlans.agreements).ToList();
                else if (agreementsSTD.agreements != null)
                    combinedSTDStatePlansAgreements.agreements = agreementsSTD.agreements;
                else if (agreementsStatePlans.agreements != null)
                    combinedSTDStatePlansAgreements.agreements = agreementsStatePlans.agreements;

                if (agreementsSTD.serviceAgreements != null && agreementsStatePlans.serviceAgreements != null)
                    combinedSTDStatePlansAgreements.serviceAgreements = agreementsSTD.serviceAgreements.Concat(agreementsStatePlans.serviceAgreements).ToList();
                else if (agreementsSTD.serviceAgreements != null)
                    combinedSTDStatePlansAgreements.serviceAgreements = agreementsSTD.serviceAgreements;
                else if (agreementsStatePlans.serviceAgreements != null)
                    combinedSTDStatePlansAgreements.serviceAgreements = agreementsStatePlans.serviceAgreements;

            }
```